# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

After moving a new server, on opening my WordPress website, I'm getting this error.

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The database name, password, localhost everything is correct in wp-config.php. Seems like there is no user who have access to it.

its a vps server with centos 6

Comment: seems `user` parameter is missing, it has taken blank as user, is it the case ?

Comment: yes. That's what I'm wondering. Usually there should be 'root' right?

Comment: check.. your db config file, its not able to fetch that.. 
Also, try getting all users and try command tool to login from - `mysql**/bin`

Comment: how can i get all mysql users from ssh?

Comment: can you login as root or server credentials from ssh ?

Comment: yes. Its a vps server

Comment: then you can try a query into `USER` table.. I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109747/discussion-between-pavanjoshi-and-gijo-varghese).